# How to make full (bootable) backup of HFS+ partition

Tags: macos, mac, backup, boot

Some years ago (before switched to Mac) I have used Acronis True Image for creating/restoring full image of NTFS partitions.

Now I'm on Mac. What I want to do is somehow fully backup my bootable HFS+ partition, store an image (not obligatory an image, because if I understand correctly CCC, for example, doesn't create images) on external USB drive, then do some repartitioning on a disk and finally restore backup in one of newly created partitions.

I've noticed that it's possible to create/restore images using Disk Utility when booting from Mac OS X Install DVD. But I'm not sure about whether this tool creates full (bootable) backup or not.

Do I need to use some 3rd party software like [CCC](http://www.bombich.com/) or Disk Utility is just fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried many solutions and came to the conclusion that the best one, by far, is SuperDuper.

The free version should be fine if you're not in a hurry. The paid version can update your backup very quickly with the "smart update" feature.

Comment: Thanks. You are probably right. Something is wrong with Disk Utility. At least in my case. =(

Answer (score 2):

[Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) is free and easy, and will [make disk images](http://www.bombich.com/software/docs/CCC/Carbon%20Copy%20Cloner%20Documentation.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Do not attempt to backup a filesystem that is currently in use.  That includes whichever filesystem you are currently booted from, for example.  If you boot from the OS X Installation disc, you can certainly use Disk Utility to back up a partition on the internal HDD.  The partition includes the filesystem, and the filesystem includes the "blessed" system folder and "blessed" startup file.  As such, your image can be restored to a partition and will be bootable.  No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can restore to a bootable backup from an image created with Disk Utility. You can also use Disk Utility to restore from an existing partition.

Comment: Seems to be possible. However during restore I got an error "Restore Failure
Could not find any scan information. The source image needs to be imagescanned/scanned for restore". Images > Scan for restore... failed to due to sum system error.