# How to make an HFS+ partition bootable on Intel Macs

Tags: macos, mac, boot, partitioning, multi-boot

I'm curious about the installation procedure used when you Dual Boot two versions of OS X.

From what I understand, when you install a fresh OS X system the installer copies all the required files across (from the installation DVD in this case) to the filesystem, and then "*does some stuff* " to make the installation bootable and appear on the boot screen when you hold down the Option key. What exactly (in all the lovely/gory UNIX/Darwin detail) is this "*stuff* "?

My situation is this: I have two fully working OS X installations on two laptops. I would like to transfer the 2nd installation across to the 1st laptop and dual boot the two installations on that first laptop instead. I therefore figure I could copy (`dd`?) across everything from `/` on the 2nd installation into a new HFS+ partition on the 1st laptop. Then somehow I ask the system to make that partition bootable so it will show up in the boot menu. How can I do this?

I appreciate there are two questions there but I assume (perhaps incorrectly) that they ultimately have the same answer. I have also read [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/181542/how-to-make-full-bootable-backup-of-hfs-partition), but I want to do the entire process by hand, not with a 3rd party tool - more for education than utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but if you use `dd` to copy the entire raw volume, that should copy the boot blocks along with the filesystem contents, so nothing else should be necessary to make the volume bootable.

But I wouldn't recommend `dd`, as it can't cope with minor details like the source and destination volumes not being exactly the same size. It's also painfully slow unless you use the raw device entries (i.e. /dev/rdiskN instead of /dev/diskN).

Instead, I'd recommend the `asr` tool for copying the volume; it's smarter, and more adaptable. You can also use the Restore tab in Disk Utility (which actually uses `asr` to do the job). I'm pretty sure that `asr` also takes care of bootability, although it's been a while since I used it in this mode.

If whatever method you use doesn't make the volume properly bootable, I think all you need to do is bless the folder that contains the booter file, which is generally in /System/Library/CoreServices:

```
sudo bless --folder /Volumes/whatever/System/Library/CoreServices
```

Answer (score 0):

Make certain the drive is correctly formatted with a GUID partition table - See this article:
http://nyacomputing.com/partitioning-a-hard-drive-on-mac/

Use Disk Utility to clone your drive - See this article:
http://nyacomputing.com/how-to-create-a-bootable-clone-of-your-mac-hard-drive/

Comment: Both links seem broken